# convert ruby date to string without losing format

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to convert a Ruby `Date` object to a string. The format of the date is: `Sun, 15 Sep 2013`

However, when I convert it to a string using `#to_s` it gives me the following: `"2013-09-15"`

Instead, I want it to become: `"Sun, 15 Sep 2013"`

Comment: See `strftime`: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime

Comment: thnx will have a look into it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails formatting date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255476/rails-formatting-date)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [Date#strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime) there are so many options

```
require 'date'


date = Date.parse("Sun, 15 Sep 2013") # => #<Date: 2013-09-15 ((2456551j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

date.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y") # => "Sun, 15 Sep 2013"
```

Answer (score 7):

`strftime` works well, however, if you find that you're using the same format in multiple places, you will find using the [Rails `Date#to_formatted_s` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-i-to_formatted_s) a more appropriate option. You can use the built-in formats:

```
date.to_formatted_s(:short)
date.to_formatted_s(:long)
```

or, you can create your own formats, adding them to Date::DATE_FORMATS:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:my_format] = '%a, %d %b %Y'
date.to_formatted_s(:my_format)
```

This will keep you from spreading formatting strings throughout your app.