# Rails Date Format (To match YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I do this:

```
DateTime.now.to_s
```

I get: 
    2015-07-31T22:22:05+02:00

But I need it in this format:

```
2015-07-31 22:22:05
```

How can I format it this way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails formatting date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255476/rails-formatting-date)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since this is a common thing to want, there is a shorthand method to do this.

```
DateTime.now.to_s(:db)     #=> 2015-07-31 22:22:05
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-to_formatted_s

Comment: what is this `:db` anyone could explain?

Answer (score 15):

```
DateTime.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S")
```

[DateTime strftime method](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)

Comment: for 24 hours you should use strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

Answer (score 10):

You can use strftime function for formatting your dates

```
DateTime.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S')
```

View [here](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)