# Time ISO 8601 in Ruby

Tags: ruby, date-formatting

I am trying to return a date with this format

2015-10-07T00:32:50.877+0000

I have tested that

```
 Time.now.iso8601
 => "2015-10-21T09:47:50-04:00"
```

but i didn't have same format

tks

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `strftime` directly?

Comment: i was not sure for this part " T00:32:50.877+0000"

Comment: Do you need the millisecconds? Do it need to be in GMT or in your defined time zone (-04:00)

Comment: the jira API request the equal format "2015-10-07T00:32:50.877+0000"

Comment: The format looks the same to me. They're both ISO 8601.

Comment: i though that too but Jira refuse it. I don't get it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails formatting date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255476/rails-formatting-date)

Comment: Suggestion: Use something like Time.current.to_utc.iso8601 if you're using any kind of cloud service. AWS CloudWatch, for instance, requires 8601.

Answer (score 65):

You can use strftime yourself and create the format you want as described [here](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)

The format you specified should be `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z`

And so the complete Ruby statement would be `Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z')`

**Various ISO 8601 formats:**

```
%Y%m%d           => 20071119                  Calendar date (basic)
%F               => 2007-11-19                Calendar date (extended)
%Y-%m            => 2007-11                   Calendar date, reduced accuracy, specific month
%Y               => 2007                      Calendar date, reduced accuracy, specific year
%C               => 20                        Calendar date, reduced accuracy, specific century
%Y%j             => 2007323                   Ordinal date (basic)
%Y-%j            => 2007-323                  Ordinal date (extended)
%GW%V%u          => 2007W471                  Week date (basic)
%G-W%V-%u        => 2007-W47-1                Week date (extended)
%GW%V            => 2007W47                   Week date, reduced accuracy, specific week (basic)
%G-W%V           => 2007-W47                  Week date, reduced accuracy, specific week (extended)
%H%M%S           => 083748                    Local time (basic)
%T               => 08:37:48                  Local time (extended)
%H%M             => 0837                      Local time, reduced accuracy, specific minute (basic)
%H:%M            => 08:37                     Local time, reduced accuracy, specific minute (extended)
%H               => 08                        Local time, reduced accuracy, specific hour
%H%M%S,%L        => 083748,000                Local time with decimal fraction, comma as decimal sign (basic)
%T,%L            => 08:37:48,000              Local time with decimal fraction, comma as decimal sign (extended)
%H%M%S.%L        => 083748.000                Local time with decimal fraction, full stop as decimal sign (basic)
%T.%L            => 08:37:48.000              Local time with decimal fraction, full stop as decimal sign (extended)
%H%M%S%z         => 083748-0600               Local time and the difference from UTC (basic)
%T%:z            => 08:37:48-06:00            Local time and the difference from UTC (extended)
%Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z  => 20071119T083748-0600      Date and time of day for calendar date (basic)
%FT%T%:z         => 2007-11-19T08:37:48-06:00 Date and time of day for calendar date (extended)
%Y%jT%H%M%S%z    => 2007323T083748-0600       Date and time of day for ordinal date (basic)
%Y-%jT%T%:z      => 2007-323T08:37:48-06:00   Date and time of day for ordinal date (extended)
%GW%V%uT%H%M%S%z => 2007W471T083748-0600      Date and time of day for week date (basic)
%G-W%V-%uT%T%:z  => 2007-W47-1T08:37:48-06:00 Date and time of day for week date (extended)
%Y%m%dT%H%M      => 20071119T0837             Calendar date and local time (basic)
%FT%R            => 2007-11-19T08:37          Calendar date and local time (extended)
%Y%jT%H%MZ       => 2007323T0837Z             Ordinal date and UTC of day (basic)
%Y-%jT%RZ        => 2007-323T08:37Z           Ordinal date and UTC of day (extended)
%GW%V%uT%H%M%z   => 2007W471T0837-0600        Week date and local time and difference from UTC (basic)
%G-W%V-%uT%R%:z  => 2007-W47-1T08:37-06:00    Week date and local time and difference from UTC (extended)
```

Comment: The OP's requirement is the RFC3339 Date/Time format, which Ruby's `Time` extension `#iso8601` outputs automatically (except that it uses `Z` for UTC instead of the also allowed `+00:00`).

Comment: In ISO8601:2004 the truncated formats were removed. 20071119 is no longer a valid ISO format (also 2007-11-19 is much easier to read, and you can easily see it's a date and not some other quantity).

Answer (score 53):

If you just want to include the fractional number of seconds, you can use [DateTime#iso8601([n=0]) → string](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-iso8601):

```
pry(main)> require 'date'
pry(main)> DateTime.now.iso8601(3)
=> "2017-01-17T12:31:26.695+11:00"
```

Or in Rails:

```
pry(main)> Time.now.iso8601(3)
=> "2017-01-17T12:31:26.695+11:00"
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `DateTime.now.iso8601`? Also, you must `require 'date'` for this to work.

Comment: I think you're right @Supermitch - my answer works for rails, your answer will work for plain old ruby

Comment: I updated the answer to work with both Ruby and Rails

Answer (score 27):

It seems like the main issue is that you want the output to be UTC encoded ISO 8601 timestamp, while Ruby by default uses the timezone of the `Time` value - which is most likely, especially if you create the value using `Time.now`, your local time zone.

The solution would be to convert the `Time` value to a UTC timezone using `#utc` method:

```rb
now = Time.now
# convert to UTC and format
puts now.utc.iso8601
```

This would output `2020-04-20T20:46:31Z` - the `Z` there is equivalent to `+00:00` and means UTC (or "Zulu time" in US military jargon). Any ISO-8601 compliant implementation should accept `Z` being identical to `+00:00`.

#### Note:

The `iso8601` method on the `Time` instance is an extension. It is part of the standard library, but you have to load it explicitly using `require 'time'`. This also loads other useful extensions for the `Time` class.

Comment: You are right. I'm going to delete my comment. And then this one.

Answer (score 7):

Did you try with Date?

```
Date.new(2018,5,25).iso8601 # returns "2018-05-25"
```

For today, it would be:

```
Date.today.iso8601
```

Comment: The question is about the time format, whereas Date does not return the time part.  `Time` class does not have a method of `iso8601` as of Ruby 2.5.1.

Answer (score 2):

For a UTC time in ISO 8601:

```rb
require 'date'
DateTime.now.new_offset(0).iso8601
# => "2022-04-15T16:33:17+00:00"
```

(This works even outside of Rails.)