# Mongoid compare datetime equality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, mongoid

I have a problem with mongoid

> a = Analysis.find('59fadd2bfd52a107d90dadf7')
>
> ...
>
> b = a.updated_at.iso8601
>
> => "2017-11-08T15:16:31+01:00"
>
> Analysis.any_of({:id => '59fadd2bfd52a107d90dadf7', :updated_at => Time.zone.parse(b)}).count
>
> => 0
>
> Analysis.any_of({:id => '59fadd2bfd52a107d90dadf7', :updated_at => a.updated_at}).count
>
> => 1

I have tested a lot of things, but i always have 0 count returned

- Time.zone.parse
- DateTime.parse
- Time.parse

And I don't know how to compare that date X_X, the b variable is literally that I'm sending to my api

Comment: Why do you need to add an `updated_at` criteria if you have an ID? The id is unique anyways.

Comment: The real request is with :updated_at.neq, it's return only the entry who has been updated by someone so i'm need the id and the updated_at to compare

Comment: is the field declared as DateTime?

Comment: I'm using Mongoid::Timestamps, so from github, it's a Time field maybe it's that. I'll try later with datetime

Comment: Stupid question on my part. Of course its Timestamps. Its defined as `field :updated_at, type: Time`. https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/timestamps/updated.rb#L14

Comment: The solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262792/time-iso-8601-in-ruby, i need the fractional seconds for the comparaison

Comment: I was suspepecting it was something like this. I’ll mark it as a duplicate.