# Ruby/Rails date conversion using strptime. MM/DD/YY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, date, format

I'm parsing PDF which returns date as string in format "04/27/17". How can I convert these strings to format for storing as date in rails?

Thanks!

Comment: See this question too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255476/rails-formatting-date

Comment: Actually, those answers use strftime which doesn't work in my case. The answer provided below uses strptime - which does work. 

I shouldn't be down-voted for this question. The answers here provide an alternate method for resolution. I will edit topic to in method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Date::strptime` can initialize a date object from a wacky US-based Y2K-unaware date format. Then if you have an active record class called MyObject with a date field called `sweet_date`, it would go like this:

```
date = Date::strptime("04/27/17", "%m/%d/%y") # returns Thu, 27 Apr 2017
object = MyObject.first
object.sweet_date = date
object.save # true
```