# Format datetime string

Tags: ruby, datetime

I need my string `"Wed, 26 May 2017 14:00:00 +0800"` to be in format `2017-05-26 14:00:00 +0800` (it's ok to keep it as a string but not mandatory). What's the quickest way?

Comment: Is your input really the String or an instance of Time or DateTime? Why do you need that output (there might be better formats `iso8601`)?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "keep it as a string but not mandatory".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails formatting date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255476/rails-formatting-date)

Answer (score 13):

[`parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-parse) the string and reformat it via [`strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime):

```
string = 'Wed, 26 May 2017 14:00:00 +0800'

Time.parse(string).strftime('%F %T %z')
#=> "2017-05-26 14:00:00 +0800"
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `strftime` to format date in ruby.

OR

Run `Time.now`

```
2017-05-22 15:56:51 +0530
```

OR

Try below code:

```
n="Wed, 26 May 2017 14:00:00 +0800"
m=n.to_datetime
m.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z")

output: "2017-05-26 14:00:00 +0800"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require "time"

Time.parse("Wed, 26 May 2017 14:00:00 +0800").to_s
# => "2017-05-26 14:00:00 +0800"

Time.parse("Wed, 26 May 2017 14:00:00 +0800").inspect
# => "2017-05-26 14:00:00 +0800"
```

Comment: Not sure. Hahaha.