# Rails: x.days.ago to "YYYY-MM-DD" into the html date attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to transform:

```
2.days.ago
```

to

```
"2018-08-17"
```

and render it in the `<div data-date="<%= result %>">`.

What I have tried as per [Rails formatting date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255476/rails-formatting-date):

```
<div data-date="<%= 2.days.ago.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') %>">
```

and it rendered as:

```
<div data-date="%Y-%m-%d">
```

Why?

Comment: Check the value of `result`. `<div data-date="<%= 2.days.ago.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') %>">` works well.

Comment: You are right, it was my mistake